# Android Widget from older Api

Tags: android, xamarin.android, numberpicker

I'm using the numberpicker widget from a older vision of the API. The one with button's(increment / decrement). After rebuild of on my android. It uses the new numberpicker widget. Is there a way to force android to use the older version of widget only.

In the manifest.xml i already put the following line:
`<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="12" android:minSdkVersion="12" />`

but it doesn't work.
Change the theme to cann't be dont because of other elements on the page.